# Save QQmlApplicationEngine render to SVG

Tags: qt, svg, qml

I am using QQmlApplicationEngine to render a QML file and would like to get the QGraphicsScene in order to save the output as SVG, does anyone know how to get this?

(I would like to render my QML output to a SVG file. I have found a lot of solutions in C++ but I lack the deeper knowledge of the Qt rendering pipeline to get the correct classes from the QML.

In this link ( https://forum.qt.io/topic/6008/how-to-save-a-qgraphicsscene-to-an-svg-file/5 ) a QGraphicsScene is used as input for a QSvgGenerator to generate an SVG, thus the question.)

Comment: You have an XY problem. Your goal is to create a .svg using the QQmlApplicationEngine rendering information but you ask about getting a QGraphicsScene. QML and QtWidgets are 2 orthogonal technologies. Note: QQmlApplicationEngine (and QML) does not use any QGraphicsScene objects.

Comment: You can find the `QQuickWindow` from the engine and write it to a `QImage` using `QQuickWindow::grabWindow()`, but that's raster graphics. Any `QWidget` (and `QGraphicsScene`) can be rendered to SVG, but you have neither at hands here.